# Java iText move watermark position

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I have the following code that scales an image to A4 size :

```
  void scale(PdfDocument pdfDocument, Rectangle pageSize, Rectangle pageBodySize) {
    int n = pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages();

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        PdfPage page = pdfDocument.getPage(i);

        MarginFinder marginFinder = new MarginFinder();
        PdfCanvasProcessor pdfCanvasProcessor = new PdfCanvasProcessor(marginFinder);
        pdfCanvasProcessor.processPageContent(page);
        Rectangle boundingBox = marginFinder.getBoundingBox();
        if (boundingBox == null || boundingBox.getWidth() == 0 || boundingBox.getHeight() == 0) {
            LOG.warn("Cannot scale page %d contents with bounding box %s\n", i, boundingBox);
            continue;
        } else {
            // Scale and move content into A4 with margin
            double scale = 0, xDiff = 0, yDiff = 0;
            double xScale = pageBodySize.getWidth() / boundingBox.getWidth();
            double yScale = pageBodySize.getHeight() / boundingBox.getHeight();
            if (xScale < yScale) {
                yDiff = boundingBox.getHeight() * (yScale / xScale - 1) / 2;
                scale = xScale;
            } else {
                xDiff = boundingBox.getWidth() * (xScale / yScale - 1) / 2;
                scale = yScale;
            }

            AffineTransform transform = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(pageBodySize.getLeft() + xDiff, pageBodySize.getBottom() + yDiff);
            transform.scale(scale, scale);
            transform.translate(-boundingBox.getLeft(), -boundingBox.getBottom());

            new PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamBefore(), page.getResources(), pdfDocument)
                    .concatMatrix(transform);

        }
        page.setMediaBox(pageSize);
        page.setCropBox(pageSize);
    }
}
```

This method is invoked here :

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream mergedPdfStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfDocument mergedPdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(mergedPdfStream));

    for (PdfDocument doc : pdfDocuments) {
        int n = doc.getNumberOfPages();
       
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
           
            PdfPage page = doc.getPage(i).copyTo(mergedPdf);
            mergedPdf.addPage(page);
            
        }
    }

    Rectangle pageSize = PageSize.A4;
    Rectangle pageBodySize = pageSize.clone().applyMargins(6, 6, 6, 6, false);
    scale(mergedPdf, pageSize, pageBodySize);
    mergedPdf.close();
```

This is working fine , however all my pages have a watermark and this watermark after the scaling is being placed almost at the center of the page and I need to set the watermark of the pages at the bottom of each page AFTER scaling the Pdf to A4.

How can I achieve this ?

EDIT: I add the watermarks this way:

```
 private byte[] addWatermark(final byte[] content, final String watermarkText, final Integer[] RgbColor, final Integer position) {
    final ByteArrayOutputStream pdfByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] newPdfContent = new byte[0];
    Document document = null;

    try {
        document = createPdf(content, pdfByteArrayOutputStream);
        final Paragraph watermark = createWaterMark(watermarkText, RgbColor);
        addWatermarkToDocumentPages(document, watermark, position);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        LOG.error("Error while adding watermark to Shipping Label, ", e);
    } finally {
        if (Objects.nonNull(document)) {
            document.close();
            newPdfContent = pdfByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        }
    }

    return newPdfContent;
}
```

EDIT 2:

addWatermarkToDocumentPages do the following:

```
 private void addWatermarkToDocumentPages(final Document document, final Paragraph watermark, final Integer position) {
    final PdfDocument pdfDocument = document.getPdfDocument();
    final int pages = pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages();

    // transparency
    final PdfExtGState gs1 = new PdfExtGState();
    gs1.setFillOpacity(0.9f);

    for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++) {
        final PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfDocument.getPage(i));
        final PdfPage pdfPage = pdfDocument.getPage(i);
        final Rectangle pageSize = pdfPage.getPageSizeWithRotation();
        pdfPage.setIgnorePageRotationForContent(true);

        pageSize.increaseHeight(WATERMARK_MARGIN_SIZE);
        pageSize.moveDown(WATERMARK_MARGIN_SIZE);
        pdfPage.setMediaBox(pageSize);

        final float x = (pageSize.getLeft() + pageSize.getRight()) / 2;
        canvas.saveState();
        canvas.setExtGState(gs1);
        document.showTextAligned(watermark, x, position, i, TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE, 0);
        canvas.restoreState();
    }
}
```

EDIT 3:

This is my createPdf method

```
private Document createPdf(final byte[] content, final ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    try {
        final PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(content)), new PdfWriter(outputStream));
        return new Document(pdfDocument);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw new IOException("Error while creating the PDF Document, ", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are different ways watermarks may be applied. E.g. there are watermark annotations but watermarks can also be part of the regular content. Which kinds of watermarks are you talking about?

Comment: @mkl I've edited my question adding the method that adds the watermark

Comment: What does `addWatermarkToDocumentPages` do? `addWatermark` does not itself add watermarks but delegates that.

Comment: @mkl Ive edited adding the method addWatermarkToDocumentPages

Comment: OK, so the watermark is added to the content. I'm afraid that makes moving it a bit difficult, something added like content is usually behaving like content and difficult to change. Can you not wait until after merging and resizing before watermarking?

Comment: Yes,  but I don't know how to resize before watermarking , how should I adapt the scale method to fit at the start of "addWatermark" method?

Comment: Resizing before watermarking is trivial. But where exactly do you want the watermark to be eventually?

Comment: I want the watermark at the bottom of the page

Comment: Shall the watermarks differ on pages from different documents or are they the same?

Comment: All the watermarks are the same across the documents

Comment: Then how about first merging the documents, then scaling them to A4, then watermarking? Or, considering that your watermarking also extends the page sizes downwards (unless they have explicit crop boxes, that is), first merging, then scaling to A4 minus WATERMARK_MARGIN_SIZE, then watermarking?

Comment: I like the first aproach , but I don't know how to do adapt the scale to work at the start of addWatermark method

Comment: *"I don't know how to do adapt the scale to work at the start of addWatermark method"* - What adaption do you consider necessary? Have you tried simply calling `scale` for `pdfDocument` with the desired target sizes and something went wrong?

Comment: scale method receives a PdfDocument as parameter and at the start of addWatermark method I have a byte[ ] array , because of this little inconvenience I can't simply use scale method before adding watermark , how can I adapt this ?

Comment: `addWatermark` retrieves a `Document` from some unknown `createPdf` method. And in `addWatermarkToDocumentPages` you show that you know how to retrieve the underlying `PdfDocument` of a `Document`. How about trying to scale right after the `createPdf` call? (And yes, depending on what `createPdf` actually does, this attempt might fail and an alternative must be attempted.)

Comment: I've tried right after createPdf call:
   document = createPdf(content, pdfByteArrayOutputStream);
            Rectangle pageSize = PageSize.A4;
            Rectangle pageBodySize = pageSize.clone().applyMargins(6, 6, 6, 6, false);
            scale(document.getPdfDocument(), pageSize, pageBodySize);
However , the page hasn't been scaled . I've edited my post adding the createPdf method.

Comment: I think you already use the page size of your scaled document then you put the watermark into the middle of the page at your addWatermark method. Is that correct? If that's the case then it's normal behaviour that your watermark is at the middle

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @JRichardsz no , I didn't

Comment: Could you share a minimal runnable sample?

Comment: I've posted all the code I could , the code I've posted is embedded into a complex system that I can't just copy-paste here